# Lazy loading with p:panel?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using `PrimeFaces 4.0`. I have a collapsible `p:panel` in a collapsed state. Is there a way to lazy load the content of the panel when the user clicks on the `+` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is no!

Answer (score 2):

That's true, there is no out-of-the-box implementation. BUT you have a toggleListener which you can use to implement it on your own.